# Recognition of a date as a date in Access Forms filtering

Tags: ms-access, filter, type-mismatch

I have an Access data table with the Field "RequiredUntil", which is from the type "Date/Time", and several other columns, and a form, in which I show that table, and where I usually use right mouse click to filter for what I want. The text box for "RequiredUntil" is formatted as "Short Date".

Part of the form:

[image: Picture of part of the form]

When I now do a right click on the field "RequiredUntil" in that form, Access properly recognizes that as a date, and offers me several date filters, i.e. Today, "This week", Past,... So I don't use any SQL there, all is done by Access!

When I select "Today" (or Yesterday or Tomorrow), I get a "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error.
When I select "This week" (or any other time period), the filter is properly set - but as soon as I filter the next column, I get a

```
    Syntax Error in Query expression '((Year([DataTable].[RequiredUntil])=Year(Date())) AND 
    (DatePart("ww";[DataTable].[RequiredUntil];0)=DatePart("ww",Date(),0))'.
```

In that case, the date filter is revoked, and only the second filter is applied.

So, I don't do any SQL, RequiredUntil is of the type Date/Time, the text field in the Form is Date/Time, Access recognizes it as Date - what am I missing?

Comment: Seems like a bug. I can reproduce the same error for "tomorow" and "yesterday". Could you please add your full version and build number of Access?

Comment: Version 2202, Build 14931.20646-Click-To-Run in Office 365.

Comment: Maybe due to my computers German locale, which is giving the date as 19.08.2022, and not 2022/08/19? But Access should get that, shouldn't it? Especially if it is showing the date German style...

Comment: Yes, it seems like a localisation issue where _colon_ and _semicolon_ are mixed up. I've reported it to MS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, the issue is caused by *Null* values in your date field.

If removed, you can set the filter, which will reveal as:

```vb
(DateSerial(Year([DataTable].[RequiredUntil]), Month([DataTable].[RequiredUntil]), Day([DataTable].[RequiredUntil])) = Date()+1)
```

which, obviously, will fail, as `DateSerial` doesn't accept *Null* values.

Comment: The _Null_ values solved the "Today/Tomorrow" Issue - but interestingly enough not the issue with the date periods, that is still the same. I will double-check if I have some hidden entries in the db.

Comment: You are right. I can reproduce this as well. Reported to MS.